# Playwright: is there a selector for the text *inside* an <input>?

Tags: css-selectors, automated-tests, playwright, playwright-python

I'm trying to do some automated testing in Dynamics 365, whose tables look like this

[image: table].

Each 'cell' here is an `<input>` element.

[image: element]

Inside that element is a link of some kind that directs you to another page. It's not an anchor `<a>`, or a `<button>`, but it nonetheless **requires that you click in the text area**--and not elsewhere within the input.

The problem is that if an input *field* is arbitrarily large: when Playwright goes to click on its center, it will end up clicking an area which isn't necessarily within the bounds of the text area.

[image: misclick]

The way I'm currently dealing with this is by using the `position` optional argument to [`Locator.click()`](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/api/class-locator#locator-click)

```py
page.get_by_role("textbox", name="Reference").click(position={"x": 10, "y": 15})
```

But that will seem inelegant if there exists a more exacting way of selecting the text itself. So I'm curious. Thanks!

Comment: Can you share your code so far?

Comment: Locators have a [boundingBox property](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/api/class-locator#locator-bounding-box) but I don't know if that will help you beyond what you currently have....

Comment: There's no such locator because no such element exists in DOM. If only text is clickable for some reason your click with position is correct

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you click on the text you need?

```
page.locator('text=563821680').first.click()
```

Comment: My particular reason is that I don't know the text before script execution. Though this might be useful for googlers who stumble on this question.